# Rare binary numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm, .net, mathematics, binary-search

Rare numbers are the natural numbers in their binary forms in which there aren't two (or more) ones next to each other. Make a program that will give the N. rare number!

For example:

> In case of N = 3 the output will be 4

Here is my trivial solution:

```
    int nd = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    int counter = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < nd)
    {

        string binary = Convert.ToString(counter, 2);
        bool founded = false;
        int j = 1;
        while(j < binary.Length && !founded)
        {
            if (binary[j-1] == '1' && binary[j] == '1')
            {
                founded = true;
            }
            j++;
        }
        if (founded == false)
        {
            i++;
        }

        counter++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(counter -1);
```

It works, but there must be a smarter and faster way to figure out the solution.

Comment: Incidental, but `found` is the past-participle of `to find`, same as the simple past tense (as opposed to `founded`).

Comment: Thanks ;), english is not my native language, but I’m trying very hard.

Comment: Can you check your example? Unless I am misunderstanding something, the first "rare numbers" are 1, 2, 4, 5, ..., so the 3rd one would be 4 and not 20.

Comment: You are right, i corrected the post

Comment: For reference: https://oeis.org/A003714

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do the computation of the "n<sup>th</sup> rare number" in a function,
so that it is separated from the rest of the program, and can be tested easily:

```
public static int RareNumber(int n)
{
    // ...      
}

public static void Main()
{
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine(RareNumber(n));
}
```

Some feedback with regard to your current code:

- The variable names are confusing. `i` counts how many rare numbers
  have been found so far, and `counter` is the current rare number.
  `founded` (or `found`) does not tell anything about *what* is found.
- The while-loop can be written more concisely as a for-loop.
- The final subtraction of `1` can be avoided if the number is incremented
  at the beginning of the loop.
- I would always write `if (condition == false)` as `if (!condition)`.

Putting it together, the function could look like this:

```
public static int RareNumber(int nd)
{
    int i = 0; // The current rare number
    int counter = 1; // How many have been found to far
    while (counter < nd)
    {
        i++;
        string binary = Convert.ToString(i, 2);
        bool repeatedOne = false;
        for (var j = 1; j < binary.Length && !repeatedOne; j++)
        {
            if (binary[j-1] == '1' && binary[j] == '1')
            {
                repeatedOne = true;
            }
        }
        if (!repeatedOne)
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

The first improvement would be to make the test faster. The conversion
from a number to a string is slow. Testing for adjacent "ones" in
the binary representation can be done with simple integer arithmetic:
A number `i` is rare exactly if `i` and `i >> 1` have no bit in common:

```
public static int RareNumber(int n)
{
    int i = 0; // The current rare number
    int counter = 1; // How many have been found to far
    while (counter < n)
    {
        i++;
        if ((i & i >> 1) == 0)
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

For even better performance, the "brute-force" approach must be
replaced by a more sophisticated algorithm.
For these kinds of problems, the 
[On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences®](http://oeis.org)
can be a valuable resource.

If you enter the first rare numbers 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 16, 17, 18, 20
into the search field then you'll find
[A003714 Fibbinary numbers](https://oeis.org/A003714),
where a different definition in terms of the Fibonacci numbers is
given. There is only a difference by one in the index: Your code
computes

```
R(1) = 0, R(2) = 1, R(3) = 2, R(4) = 4, ...
```

whereas A003714 has

```
a(0) = 0, a(1) = 1, a(2) = 2, a(3) = 4, ...
```

From the formula at A003714 one can derive that for \$ n \$ between two
consecutive Fibonacci numbers 
$$
  F_k < n \le F_{k+1} 
$$
we have
$$
  R(n) = 2^{k-1} + R(n - F_k) \, .
$$
(You should make a list with the first 20 rare numbers and convince yourself of the
correctness!)

This can be implemented as a recursive function, which should be quite
fast because the Fibonacci numbers grow quickly:

```
public static int RareNumber(int n)
{
    if (n <= 2)
    {
        return n - 1;
    }

    // Two consecutive Fibonacci numbers F(k), F(k+1):
    var f0 = 1;
    var f1 = 2;
    // Corresponding power 2 ** (k-1)
    var p = 1;

    while (f1 < n) {
        // Next pair of Fibonacci numbers:
        var tmp = f0;
        f0 = f1;
        f1 = tmp + f1;
        p <<= 1;
    }
    // Now f0 < n <= f1

    return p + RareNumber(n - f0);
}
```